# Why doesn't my fragment with custom layout check the given checkedItem

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment which shows single choice items with radio buttons.

Here is my code:

```
   SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(
    getActivity(),
    listItem, //this is a hashmap
    R.layout.my_custom_list_item,
    new String[] { "id", "name", "status" },
    new int[] { R.id.textview_ID, R.id.textview_name, R.id.textview_status });
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Title").setSingleChoiceItems(simpleAdapter, 0, //check the first item
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInteface,int position) {
            //do something
        }
        }).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            //do something
        }
    });
```

I use `ArrayAdapter` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice` on a different place and it checks the first item. Note that i already gave `0` to the `checkedItem` parameter. I think there is a problem with my custom layout.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:paddingTop="2sp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/selected_cert"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_ID"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" >
            </TextView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="28dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name :"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" >
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="13sp" >
                </TextView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Satatus:"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_qualifiedstatus"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do i make the first custom item selected when user opens the dialog fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that i needed to create a custom LinearLayout and implement Checkable interface. Then use it as root view of my list item.

My custom LinearLayout:

```
public class CheckableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout implements Checkable {
    RadioButton mRadioButton;

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CheckableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
        findCheckableView(this);
    }

    //finds RadioButton recursively (comment if you know a better way to do that)
    void findCheckableView(ViewGroup parent) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                findCheckableView((ViewGroup) child);
            } else if (child != null) {
                if (child instanceof RadioButton) {
                    mRadioButton = (RadioButton) child;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mRadioButton != null) {
            mRadioButton.setChecked(checked);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mRadioButton != null ? mRadioButton.isChecked() : false;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if (mRadioButton != null) {
            mRadioButton.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

My List item

```xml
<com.foo.customViews.CheckableLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:paddingTop="2sp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="87dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" >
            </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- some more views -->
</com.foo.customViews.CheckableLinearLayout>
```

Here is the article which helped me:
http://tokudu.com/post/50023900640/android-checkable-linear-layout

Comment: While the article answers the question, it would be helpful if you could summarise the main code snippet from the article within your answer. One day, that link may become broken and users will no longer have access to the answer.

Comment: you are right. i will add when my code to the answer. thank you